# mysql - Friend of a friend

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a sample of my FRIENDS table

```
ID      FRIENDID
1001    1110    
1001    1005    
1002    1207    
1002    1188    
1005    1107    
1005    1001
```

I am trying to answer these questions.

- Number of friends of a particular person.
- Number of friends of friends of a particular person.
- Number of friends of friends of friends of a particular person.
- Number of friends of friends of friends of friends of a particular person.

Now the first one is easy

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM FRIENDS
WHERE friendID = 1005;
```

and the second one I came up with this

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM FRIENDS
WHERE friendID IN
(SELECT ID from FRIENDS where friendID = 1005) AND NOT ID = 1005;
```

The third and fourth one I get confused and came up with this but its not working. Have no idea what is right? I think I need to use `DISTINCT` in there to make sure there are no repeats.

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM FRIENDS
WHERE friendID IN
((SELECT ID from FRIENDS where friendID = 1005) AND NOT ID = 1005
WHERE friendID IN
(SELECT ID from FRIENDS where friendID = 1005) AND NOT ID = 1005);
```

Comment: Consider a graph db like Neo4j, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GekQqFZm7mA

Comment: @prototype This is obviously a SQL exercise, changing to a different DB isn't an option.

Comment: What version of MySQL? Version 8.0 has hierarchical queries that resolve this problem with succint queries for all levels. If you are using 5.x then it's going to look verbose and ugly as you are going it.

Comment: Hint:  `count(distinct)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Number of friends of a particular person.

That can done by `count()` function:

```
SELECT f1.id, count(DISTINCT f1.friendid) AS friends_cnt
  FROM FRIENDS AS f1
 WHERE f1.id = 1005;
```

- Number of friends of friends of a particular person.

That can be done with joining table with itself:

```
SELECT f1.id, count(DISTINCT f2.friendid) AS f_friends_cnt
  FROM FRIENDS AS f1
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f2  ON f2.id = f1.frienfid
                     AND f2.id != f1.id -- to avoid recursion
 WHERE f1.id = 1005;
```

- Number of friends of friends of friends of a particular person

Join table with itself twice:

```
SELECT f1.id, count(DISTINCT f3.friendid) AS f_f_friends_cnt
  FROM FRIENDS AS f1
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f2  ON f2.id = f1.frienfid
                     AND f2.id != f1.id 
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f3  ON f3.id = f2.frienfid
                     AND f3.id != f1.id 
                     AND f3.id != f2.id 
 WHERE f1.id = 1005;
```

- Number of friends of friends of friends of friends of a particular person.

Join table with itself three times:

```
SELECT f1.id, count(DISTINCT f4.friendid) AS f_f_f_friends_cnt
  FROM FRIENDS AS f1
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f2  ON f2.id = f1.frienfid
                     AND f2.id != f1.id 
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f3  ON f3.id = f2.frienfid
                     AND f3.id != f1.id 
                     AND f3.id != f2.id 
  JOIN FRIENDS AS f4  ON f4.id = f3.frienfid
                     AND f4.id != f1.id 
                     AND f4.id != f2.id 
                     AND f4.id != f3.id 
 WHERE f1.id = 1005;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be counting the same friend multiple times, because the same person may be a friend of different friends of the original person.

Change `SELECT COUNT(ID)` to `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)` and it won't count the same ID twice.